# Change Genymotion Wi-Fi SSID

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, androvm

Anyone know how to change the Genymotion Wi-Fi SSID name?

It is set to "WiredSSID" by default.

Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new network by clicking "+" on top of screen or delete the default setting and create new wifi ssid here you can change the name.

Comment: Where can I find that "+" button? I don't see it on the Genymotion, nor in the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please go through the screenshot.

Comment: Probably my question is not that clear. I meant, how to RENAME that "WiredSSID" from Genymotion default?